# what is the default html version for salesforce?

Tags: visualforce

1. What is the default html version for a `Visualforce Page`?
2. Will it dynamically generate based on browser? (I understand we can explicitly define the html version using docType tag)
3. Is there any salesforce defined javascript to get the browser detail about version and the CSS support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions 1 and 2 can be answered by investigating the documentation for the **[`<apex:page>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm)** tag:

> **Attribute Name**
>   docType
>
> **Attribute Type**
>   String
>
> **Description**
>   The HTML document type definition (DTD), or doctype, that describes the structure of the rendered page. Possible values for this attribute include "html-4.01-strict", "xhtml-1.0-transitional", "xhtml-1.1-basic", and "html-5.0", among others.
>
> If not specified, this value defaults to "html-4.01-transitional", which results in a doctype of `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`.
>
> For more information about HTML doctype declarations, see the [W3C specifications](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html).

So that addresses 1 directly, and the answer to 2 is that this value does *not* vary based on the client. I think question 3 is somewhat broad/off topic here. At the very least it should be a separate question.